# Install AMD OpenCL CPU driver with an Nvidia graphic card

Tags: windows, driver, opencl, nvidia, amd-processor

I have seen this question many times but never found an answer for Windows.
I recently ported my CUDA code to OpenCL.
When testing with an ATI card, the Catalyst drivers contain a CPU OpenCL driver, hence I can run the OpenCL code on the CPU.
When testing with an NVIDIA card, there is no driver for the CPU.

Question is: how can I install (and deploy) a CPU driver when running with an Nvidia card?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use OpenCL on CPU you don't need any driver, you only need OpenCL runtime that supports CPU, which (in case of AMD/ATI) is part of [APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/pages/default.aspx). It could be installed no matter what GPU you have. Your end-users would also have to install the APP SDK: currently, there is [no way](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1280710#1280710) to install OpenCL runtime only.

If you have Intel CPU, you better try [Intel OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/), which has separate installer. However, AMD APP SDK works on Intel CPUs quite well, but note vice versa.

Comment: There are some generic CPU only implementations around -- but they seem to only exist for Linux which is unfortunate ("freeocl" for example).  It would be good to see a generic fallback runtime for Windows that could at least take advantage of multi-threaded 64-bit SSE, and MMX, etc.  (It would also be awesome to see CUDA wrappers that could run on top of OpenCL).

Comment: Additionally, on my Core-i7 machine, I report that I've installed NVidia's SDK, Intel's SDK, and AMD's SDK -- the Intel and NVidia SDK's both added platforms with OpenCL devices that work -- but installing AMD's SDK did not. -- It really looks like you have to get the one that's specific for your processor. :-/